# Central Administration: entries in service application menu "new" limited?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, service-applications

what is the reason that the menu *service application => new* in CA is showing only

- App Management
- Business Data
- Secure Store

[image: new service application menu]

?
And can we get the metadata service into this menu anyhow?

Comment: what is your permission level? what version of sharepoint you are using?

Comment: system account / farm admin on SP2013 (15.0.4815.1000)

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 server or foundation? MMS is not available for foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using SharePoint foundation 2013 and Managed Metadata service is not offered for foundation.

Please check this technet for more about comparison between the SharePoint versions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint__cloud/2013/01/09/sharepoint-2013-onpremise-edition-comparison-chart/

Comment: omg yes, thanks Waqas, I didn't recognize that it is a Foundation